# JSX prop syntax

Tags: reactjs, jsx

In JSX, you can specify string literal props in two ways:

```
<input id={'active_input'} />
```

and

```
<input id="active_input" />
```

Is there a name for each of those syntaxes?

Comment: The first one is an expression which in this case happens to evaluate to a string.

Answer (score 2):

I don't find an authoritative source for the following but I would say:
`<input id={'active_input'} />` is a string literal inside a JS expression and
`<input id="active_input" />` is a string literal.

There is but a (in my opinion) significant distinction between the two:
The first one is HTML-unescaped but the second one is just a string literal.

So the following are not equal:

```
<MyComponent message="<3" />
<MyComponent message={'<3'} />
```

The following are equal:

```
<MyComponent message="&lt;3" />
<MyComponent message={'<3'} />
```

Source: [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Answer (score 0):

`<input id={'active_input'} />` is a React syntax. You can pass basically whatever you wish, a `string`, a `boolean`, an `array` and so on.

`<input id="active_input" />` is a basic HTML syntax. It's limited to pass only the strings, so it's not kind of useful when it comes to pass various props.